# Detect protocol with finatra

Tags: https, finatra

Hello I'm faily new with Finatra and wanted to know if there is a way to validate that a request was made using the **https** protocol?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always use HTTPS you can disable the http server server

```
import com.twitter.finagle.Http
import com.twitter.finatra.http.HttpServer
import com.twitter.finatra.http.routing.HttpRouter

object ExampleHttpsServerMain extends ExampleHttpsServer

class ExampleHttpsServer
  extends HttpServer
  with Tls {

  override val defaultHttpPort: String = "" // disable the default HTTP port
  override val defaultHttpsPort: String = ":443"

  override def configureHttp(router: HttpRouter): Unit = {
    router
      .add[ExampleController]
  }
}
```

But if you want for some specific controller or route to check if it is https for example Login should only be used via https then you can define [Filters](https://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/http/filters.html)  for example:

Per Route

```
class ExampleController @Inject()(
  exampleService: ExampleService
) extends Controller {

  filter[ExampleFilter].get("/ping") { request: Request =>
    "pong"
  }

  filter[ExampleFilter]
    .filter[AnotherExampleFilter]
    .get("/name") { request: Request =>
    response.ok.body("Bob")
  }

  filter(new OtherFilter).post("/foo") { request: Request =>
    exampleService.do(request)
    "bar"
  }
}
```

Per Controller

```
import DoEverythingModule
import ExampleController
import ExampleFilter
import com.twitter.finagle.http.Request
import com.twitter.finatra.http.filters.AccessLoggingFilter
import com.twitter.finatra.http.routing.HttpRouter
import com.twitter.finatra.http.{Controller, HttpServer}

object ExampleServerMain extends ExampleServer

class ExampleServer extends HttpServer {

  override val modules = Seq(
    DoEverythingModule)

  override def configureHttp(router: HttpRouter) {
    router
      .add[ExampleFilter, ExampleController]
  }
}
```

If you check all implementations of **SimpleFilter** you may find some filters that you can reuse or base your filter from.